# why channel is not receiving being member of struct

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

Code : https://play.golang.org/p/Oh3oTa7GIPX

```
type a struct {
    c chan bool
}

func (a *a) do() {
    a.c <- true
}

type b struct {
    c chan bool
    a a
}

func main() {
    b := b{
        c: make(chan bool),
        a: a{c: make(chan bool)},
    }

    go b.s()
    b.c <- true

    // below is to stay main gorutine alive
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        done <- true
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            fmt.Println("Done!")
            return
        }
    }
}

func (b *b) s() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-b.c:
            fmt.Println("b c")
            b.a.do()

        case <-b.a.c:
            fmt.Println("b a c")
        }
    }
}
```

Actual Output of above is

```
b c
Done!
```

Expected Ouput:

```
b c
b a c
Done !
```

I am not getting why is it not printing `b a c` ?

Code is self explanatory, if it still requires more details please ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main` goroutine sends a value on `b.c`, then waits:

```
b.c <- true
```

The goroutine you launch from main:

```
go b.s()
```

This is the one that receives from `b.c`, and also from `b.a.c`:

```
func (b *b) s() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-b.c:
            fmt.Println("b c")
            b.a.do()

        case <-b.a.c:
            fmt.Println("b a c")
        }
    }
}
```

If a value is received from `b.c`, this goroutine attempts to send on `b.a.c` (in `a.do()` method), and you expect this *same* goroutine to receive from `b.a.c`. But since `b.a.c` is unbuffered, the send will block, so it will never reach the next iteration in `b.s()` where it could / would receive from `b.a.c`.

If a channel is unbuffered, a send on it may only proceed if there is another goroutine ready to receive from it.

If you make the `b.a.c` channel buffered, a send on it can proceed without blocking, so in the next iteration it can be received:

```
a: a{c: make(chan bool, 1)}
```

With this change you get your expected output. Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/C-QJ2RbIs2w).

Comment: thanks for beautiful explanation,  so i created a deadlock situation here, right?

Comment: @mkmayank No, it's not a deadlock, because the `main()` goroutine can proceed once the timer is up. In a deadlock all goroutines are blocked, waiting for each other or some event that will never occur.